# Twig renders / display only the view path

Tags: php, model-view-controller, twig

I'm creating an mvc structure for learning/teaching purpouses and so far I could set up the structure and a controller plus twig as template system.

The structure is:

- index.php
- controllers/

  - error.php
- inc/

  - controller_base.php
  - view_manager.php
- views/

  - .cache/
  - error/

    - view.html

So:

- index instantiate twig autoloader (and mvc autoloader by spl_register).
- index instantiate error controller inheriting controller_base.
- controller_base is holding the view_manager.
- error call view_manager to display the `error/view.html` and the only thing I get on the browser is `error/view.html`.

No errors on the apache log. (`error_reporting(E_ALL)`)
Twig cache files created correctly, but the content doesn't look good to me:

```
protected function doDisplay(array $context, array $blocks = array()) {
    // line 1
    echo "error/view.html";
}
```

Anyone knows why, and how can I print the actual view?
Thanks in advance.

Code:
index.php: Declaring autoloaders

```
function __autoload($class_name)
{
if(file_exists("controllers/$class_name.php")): 
    include strtolower("controllers/$class_name.php");
elseif(file_exists("models/$class_name.php")):
    include strtolower("models/$class_name.php");
elseif(file_exists("inc/$class_name.php")):
    include strtolower("inc/$class_name.php");
endif;
}
spl_autoload_register('__autoload');

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Twig_Autoloader::register(); has been avoided cause Twig installation was done by composer.
Adding it doesn't bring any change.

error.php (controller): called method.

```
public function show($param)
{  
    $this->viewMng->display(get_class().$data['view'], array())
}
```

controller_base.php:

```
class base
{
    protected $viewMng;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->viewMng = new viewmanager();
        }
}
```

viewmanager.php: whole class

```
class viewmanager {

    private $twig;
    protected $template_dir = 'views/';
    protected $cache_dir = 'views/.cache';
//  protected $vars = array();

    public function __construct($template_dir = null) {

        if ($template_dir !== null) {
            // Check here whether this directory really exists
            $this->template_dir = $template_dir;
        }

        $loader = new Twig_Loader_String($this->template_dir);
        $this->twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
                        'cache' => $this->cache_dir));
    }

    public function render($template_file, $data = array()) {

        if (!file_exists($this->template_dir.$template_file)) {
            throw new Exception('no template file ' . $template_file . ' present in directory ' . $this->template_dir);
        }

        return $this->twig->render($template_file, $data);

    }

    public function display($template_file, $data) {

        if (!file_exists($this->template_dir.$template_file)) {
            throw new Exception('no template file ' . $template_file . ' present in directory ' . $this->template_dir);
        }
        $tmpl = ($this->twig->loadTemplate($template_file));//print_r($tmpl);
        $tmpl->display($data);
    }
}
```

view.html:

```
<html><body> Hello </body></html>
```

Comment: can you post the code of "error call view_manager to display the error/view.html"?

Comment: Sorry, I've added all the relevant code. If there's something else you want to see, just ask. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: what happens when you call `echo $this->viewMng->render(get_class().$data['view'], array())`? Also why are there brackets: `$tmpl = ($this->twig->loadTemplate($template_file));` ?

Comment: render function produce exactly the same result.
No reason for the brackets. Probably resulting of different options edited and tried. They will go away at the end, for sure.
Also tried to place the template at the view root folder, same result. It's not a problem on the path cause otherwise it produces an exception.
Edited on the question: doDisplay in the "compiled file" only contains "echo 'error/view.html';". Don't know if this is normal, but maybe it helps solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is based on the loader.
According to the Twig documentation:

> Twig_Loader_String loads templates from strings. It's a dummy loader
>   as the template reference is the template source code
>  This
>   loader should only be used for unit testing as it has severe
>   limitations: several tags, like extends or include do not make sense
>   to use as the reference to the template is the template source code
>   itself.

That's why it only prints the passed in string.
Twig_Loader_String, should be replaced by the proper loader.
In this case it works perfectly well Twig_Loader_Filesystem.

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($this->template_dir);
```

This solve the problem and the MVC structure works completely fine.
Thanks taking a look, guys.